# android how to draw on a canvas through touch events

Tags: android

I want to make android-screen as white-board so that by touch on screen I able to draw something on screen.
I know I have to use canvas, Path all these things. But how I can make that screen so that i able to draw a dot there?
For that what should i do with my activity?
How can I do that plz give me some sample code.

Thank you

Comment: More specific question needed, you can ask about something you can't make, and not about something you don't know how to make.

Comment: I wanna screen should work as a surface. so that by touch on screen I able to draw a dot on screen. How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

So maybe you should take a look to this example:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/graphics/TouchPaint.html

Comment: In this example it extends GraphicsActivity. I tried before but it not supports(I am working with Android 2.2) . How can i use with this?

Comment: without using GraphicsActivity any other way there?

Comment: Well, right now I can think other way. You have to create your onw view, so have a class that extend "View" class. In that, override the methods: "onDraw" and "onTouchEvent". Use "onTouchEvent" to know where is the finger, and "onDraw" to paint on the screen. (take a look to the code in this link: http://www.android-spa.com/viewtopic.php?t=8474&highlight=pintar , is a spanish forum, but the code can give you an overall view of what I!m trying to explain).

Comment: Another way can be using gestures, take a look here: http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html